# How to deal with timeouts in botframework SDK3 C#

Tags: botframework

I'm so sorry that I'm a newbie that I have so many questions.

My Bot state is save in DB. So it would never timeout. And I use teams.
But I want to restart conversation if user don't reply for 10 minutes.

**This is my solution.**
According [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2496), I also made a static dictionary which could help me to handle every conversations' timer easily. And with the help of [Sample Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages/simpleSendMessage/ConversationStarter.cs), I did interrupt the stack. But once it's finished, it will be back to the original conversation. To solve this problem. I cleared the state according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983438/microsoft-bot-framework-clear-conversation-state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are a number of ways to solve this but here is one way you can try.

In your Global.asax

Define this cancellation token source for your thread

```
 CancellationTokenSource _getTokenAsyncCancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

In Application_Start() code setup a Task thread with a while loop. It will look something like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                while (!_getTokenAsyncCancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Check timespan between last message timestamp vs NOW
                        //if timespan > 9 minutes
                        //   send message 
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
                    }
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), _getTokenAsyncCancellation.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Also, add an Application_edn method to sht things down cleanly

```
protected void Application_End()
        {
            _getTokenAsyncCancellation.Cancel();
        }
```

Now, you're not quite done. You will also need somewhat to track the user's last message timestamp. Basically, each time the bot receives a new message from the user yo will set this timestamp and the code in your while loop will check against that.

I hope this helps and gives you some ideas on what to try.

Comment: Thanks you so much.. Sorry, I'm a really newbie. Can you tell me how to send the message here"//   send message ". and when will Application_End be called?

Comment: This starts to get really complicated and should probably be a separate questions. Take a look at this [Sample Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages/simpleSendMessage/ConversationStarter.cs) in GitHib. It shows how to create and ad-hoc message. This is what you'll be doing in your thread. You'll need a way to get all the necessary ids and values. You can probably store then in state along with the last message time.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea to close all the conversations in MS teams?