# How to switch Dialogs in BotFramework SDK3 C#

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to add a timeout Dialog using proactiveMessages. If user doesn't reply to [A dialog], [timeout dialog] comes out. So I think timeout dialog should be the current dialog. But do I to close other dialog [A dialog]?

According [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4774), it seems **context.EndConversation** was not working in MS Teams. Of course I have tried again. It is still not working.

I also tried the way below. But it seems not working either.

```
      using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, context.Activity.AsMessageActivity()))
        {

            var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
            await botData.LoadAsync(default(CancellationToken));
            var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();
            stack.Reset();
            await botData.FlushAsync(default(CancellationToken));
        }
```

Any suggestions about changing the dialog?

Comment: What do you mean by "ending all conversation"? Stopping current dialogs? Because that's what you are trying to do in your code snippet

Comment: @NicolasR I'm trying to add a timeout Dialog using proactiveMessages. If user don't reply [A dialog], [timeout dialog] comes out.  So I think timeout dialog is the current dialog. But how to close other dialog [A dialog]?

Comment: With regard to the difference between a conversation and a dialog:
A conversation is the id/state for the entire context of the interaction between the user and the bot. What you are referring to as "conversation" is actually a dialog. A dialog is generally a class that defines a single interaction that a user can have with your bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods of redirecting dialog flow within a C# bot.

you can use [`context.Forward()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#invoke-the-new-order-dialog) to send a user to a new dialog starting with a message that you are currently processing:

`await context.Forward(new NewOrderDialog(), this.ResumeAfterNewOrderDialog, message, CancellationToken.None);`

or you can use [`context.call()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#passing-state-between-dialogs) to send a user to a new dialog and start from scratch there:

`context.Call(new AgeDialog(this.name), this.AgeDialogResumeAfter);`

The "ResumeAfter" functions can be defined anywhere (including a function within the new dialog itself) and setting these to where you would like to redirect the user after they have finished with your timeout dialog will allow you to determine the flow.

Comment: I still couldn't figure out how to make a timeout dialog. Could you give me some suggestion? This is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073731/how-to-deal-with-timeouts-in-botframework-sdk3-c-sharp